# Generate waveform image for audio file?

Tags: sound, gstreamer, previews

What is the proper `gst-launch` sink chain to use any one of the [audiovisualizers](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-bad-plugins/html/gst-plugins-bad-plugins-plugin-audiovisualizers.html)?

Any other tool that is working?

I've seen the http://rg42.org/wiki/sndfile-waveform

But before trying to dive into compiling it, maybe there is a way to do it with gstreamer? Or anyone who can confirm that it will compile fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the Gstreamer audiovisualizers as all of them are only creating a frame for a scope-like renderer (i.e. a video sink, such as ximagesink)

Let's take the `/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/bell.ogg` as a sample file.

If I open this file in audacity I can see a preview of the waveform:

[image]

But if I use the following pipeline:

```
gst-launch filesrc location=/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/bell.ogg ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! wavescope ! jpegenc ! filesink location=waveform.jpg
```

I only get a truncated waveform corresponding to the first samples of my file:

[image]

[sndfile-waveform](http://gareus.org/wiki/sndfile-waveform) is as you can guess, the perfect tool for this task but requires to be built from source (It will install ~200MB of dependencies though):

1. Install all the dependencies

   ```
   sudo apt-get build-dep sndfile-tools 
   sudo apt-get install octave-signal libsamplerate0-dev git
   ```
2. Clone the [sndfile-tools](https://github.com/erikd/sndfile-tools) repo

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/erikd/sndfile-tools.git
   ```
3. Build sndfile-tools binaries:

   ```
   cd sndfile-tools/
   ./autogen.sh 
   ./configure 
   make
   ```
4. Create a waveform with `sndfile-waveform` (default channel is 0, it can be changed with the `--channel` option)

   ```
   ./bin/sndfile-waveform /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/desktop-login.ogg waveform.png
   ```

   The result png file:

[image]

The same file in audacity:

[image]

Comment: Created https://github.com/erikd/sndfile-tools/issues/22

Comment: @int_ua: Those build dependencies should be installed by `sudo apt-get build-dep sndfile-tools`. If not run `sudo apt-get install libsndfile1-dev libjack-dev libfftw3-dev libcairo2-dev`

Comment: Strangely, I was sure i ran it yesterday, but today it still installed new packages. Thanks.